# Crystal Reports - uninstall old version before installing new

Tags: windows, crystal-reports, wix, custom-action

I have created a bundle for my project that checks for Crystal Reports and will install it if it doesn't exist.
My issue is I need to uninstall the old Crystal Reports if it exists first.
Say the user has Crystal Reports v13.0.10 and we need to upgrade them to v13.0.31. SAP requires to uninstall 13.0.10 first before installing 13.0.31. Is this possible using bundle?
Using WiX Toolset v3.11.2.4516. Visual Studio 2015.
Thank you.

Comment: Better to ask in SAP forum, but if there no issue, then do not uninstall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a feature request for this at https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/4858, but no one has implemented it yet.

Theoretically, you could add `MsiPackage`s for all of the problematic versions and make their `InstallCondition` always false. It's probably more practical to write your own `ExePackage` that uninstalls the problematic versions.